# Problems installing Torch on Windows 10 with torch/distro

Tags: torch

I am trying to install Torch according to the instruction [enter link description here](https://github.com/torch/distro). My environment is:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2017
- cmake version 3.16.0-rc3
- conda version 4.7.12
- Cuda 10.0

However, when I run install.bat, using the vs command prompt, the installation freezes (see image). Has anyone managed to install using this repository?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDtC7.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the error you are seeing here as text instead of an image? it will make search engines work better, your friends happy, and you getting an answer much quicker.

Comment: That is actually the problem, no error is being displayed. It get stuck in this part without any feedback for hours. I looked into the script and it should have displayed an error or a confirmation message. I wonder if it is a compatibility problem. I saw references to Cuda 9, I wonder what is the most stable configuration. However, the repository seem to be abandoned.